# Calculated Column Generating before Other Columns?

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a unique identifier using a combination of a few letters and numbers, for example: abc1000, abc1001, abc1002. The text will always be the same and the number is based upon the item's ID plus 1000.

The current code that I have in my calculated column is as follows:

="abc"&([ID]+1000)

Which works perfectly fine except that for new items, it seems that the calculated column is generated before the "ID" column if that is possible. Therefore, all of my "unique" identifiers come out to be abc1000 since it thinks that my ID value is 0.

Is there a way for me to generate the ID before the calculated column or can I update the calculated column after the fact in a workflow somewhere?

Thank you!

Comment: Create a column and set its value in designer workflow. Set column parameters as ShowinNewForm, ShowInEditForm as false.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. And there is no OOTB work around. ID column won't work.

You'll need a workflow to update the field. Something simple as Edit right after it has been created.